Getting " The request to `/users/login` did not apply any authorization checks." while using Authorization in cakePHP
I am learning to implement authorization cakephp 5 using this documentation https://book.cakephp.org/5/en/tutorials-and-examples/cms/authorization.html
But i'm getting "The request to /users/login did not apply any authorization checks" error
I have looked everywhere for the error but got no solution
Here are the files
First is the article controller file. The controller for the articles file . It was created from bake command and I have put other code from the documentations
ArticlesController.php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Controller;

/**
 * Articles Controller
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Table\ArticlesTable $Articles
 */
class ArticlesController extends AppController
{
    /**
     * Index method
     *
     * @return \Cake\Http\Response|null|void Renders view
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $query = $this->Articles->find()
            ->contain(['Users']);
        $articles = $this->paginate($query);

        $this->set(compact('articles'));
        
        $this->Authorization->skipAuthorization();
    }

    /**
     * View method
     *
     * @param string|null $id Article id.
     * @return \Cake\Http\Response|null|void Renders view
     * @throws \Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException When record not found.
     */
    public function view($id = null)
    {$article = $this->Articles->get($id, contain: ['Users', 'Tags']);
        $this->set(compact('article'));

        // Update retrieving tags with contain()
        $article = $this->Articles
            ->findById($article['id'])
            ->contain('Tags')
            ->firstOrFail();
        $this->set(compact('article'));
        $this->Authorization->skipAuthorization();
    }

    /**
     * Add method
     *
     * @return \Cake\Http\Response|null|void Redirects on successful add, renders view otherwise.
     */
    public function add()
    {
       
      /*  $article = $this->Articles->newEmptyEntity();
    $this->Authorization->authorize($article);
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $article = $this->Articles->patchEntity($article, $this->request->getData());
            if ($this->Articles->save($article)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The article has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('The article could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
        $users = $this->Articles->Users->find('list', limit: 200)->all();
        $this->set(compact('article', 'users', 'tags'));


        // Get a list of tags.
        $tags = $this->Articles->Tags->find('list')->all();

        // Set tags to the view context
        $this->set('tags', $tags);

        $this->set('article', $article);
        */

        $article = $this->Articles->newEmptyEntity();
    $this->Authorization->authorize($article);

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $article = $this->Articles->patchEntity($article, $this->request->getData());

        // Changed: Set the user_id from the current user.
        $article->user_id = $this->request->getAttribute('identity')->getIdentifier();

        if ($this->Articles->save($article)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('Your article has been saved.'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to add your article.'));
    }
    $tags = $this->Articles->Tags->find('list')->all();
    $this->set(compact('article', 'tags'));
    }

    /**
     * Edit method
     *
     * @param string|null $id Article id.
     * @return \Cake\Http\Response|null|void Redirects on successful edit, renders view otherwise.
     * @throws \Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException When record not found.
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
      /*  $article = $this->Articles
        ->findById($id)
        ->contain('Tags') // load associated Tags
        ->firstOrFail();
    $this->Authorization->authorize($article);

        $article = $this->Articles
            ->findById($id)
            ->contain('Tags') // load associated Tags
            ->firstOrFail();
        if ($this->request->is(['post', 'put'])) {
            $this->Articles->patchEntity($article, $this->request->getData());
            if ($this->Articles->save($article)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('Your article has been updated.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to update your article.'));
        }

        // Get a list of tags.
        $tags = $this->Articles->Tags->find('list')->all();

        // Set tags to the view context
        $this->set('tags', $tags);

        $this->set('article', $article);

        */

        $article = $this->Articles
        ->findById($id)
        ->contain('Tags') // load associated Tags
        ->firstOrFail();
    $this->Authorization->authorize($article);

    if ($this->request->is(['post', 'put'])) {
        $this->Articles->patchEntity($article, $this->request->getData(), [
            // Added: Disable modification of user_id.
            'accessibleFields' => ['user_id' => false]
        ]);
        if ($this->Articles->save($article)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('Your article has been updated.'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to update your article.'));
    }
    $tags = $this->Articles->Tags->find('list')->all();
    $this->set(compact('article', 'tags'));
    }

    /**
     * Delete method
     *
     * @param string|null $id Article id.
     * @return \Cake\Http\Response|null Redirects to index.
     * @throws \Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException When record not found.
     */
    public function delete($id)
    {
        $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);

        $article = $this->Articles->findById($id)->firstOrFail();
        $this->Authorization->authorize($article);
        $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);
        $article = $this->Articles->get($id);
        if ($this->Articles->delete($article)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The article has been deleted.'));
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The article could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
        }

        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }

    public function tags()
{
    // The 'pass' key is provided by CakePHP and contains all
    // the passed URL path segments in the request.
    $tags = $this->request->getParam('pass');

    // Use the ArticlesTable to find tagged articles.
    $articles = $this->Articles->find('tagged', tags: $tags)
        ->all();

    // Pass variables into the view template context.
    $this->set([
        'articles' => $articles,
        'tags' => $tags
    ]);

    $this->Authorization->skipAuthorization();
}
}

This is the users controller file. The controller for the users file . It was created from bake command and I have put other code from the documentations
UsersController.php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Controller;

/**
 * Users Controller
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Table\UsersTable $Users
 */
class UsersController extends AppController
{
    /**
     * Index method
     *
     * @return \Cake\Http\Response|null|void Renders view
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $query = $this->Users->find();
        $users = $this->paginate($query);

        $this->set(compact('users'));
        $this->Authorization->skipAuthorization();
    }

    /**
     * View method
     *
     * @param string|null $id User id.
     * @return \Cake\Http\Response|null|void Renders view
     * @throws \Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException When record not found.
     */
    public function view($id = null)
    {
        $user = $this->Users->get($id, contain: ['Articles']);
        $this->set(compact('user'));
    }

    /**
     * Add method
     *
     * @return \Cake\Http\Response|null|void Redirects on successful add, renders view otherwise.
     */
    public function add()
    {
        $user = $this->Users->newEmptyEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->getData());
            if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
        $this->set(compact('user'));
        $this->Authorization->skipAuthorization();
    }

    /**
     * Edit method
     *
     * @param string|null $id User id.
     * @return \Cake\Http\Response|null|void Redirects on successful edit, renders view otherwise.
     * @throws \Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException When record not found.
     */
    public function edit($id = null)
    {
        $user = $this->Users->get($id, contain: []);
        if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->getData());
            if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
        $this->set(compact('user'));
    }

    /**
     * Delete method
     *
     * @param string|null $id User id.
     * @return \Cake\Http\Response|null Redirects to index.
     * @throws \Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException When record not found.
     */
    public function delete($id = null)
    {
        $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);
        $user = $this->Users->get($id);
        if ($this->Users->delete($user)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been deleted.'));
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
        }

        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }

    public function beforeFilter(\Cake\Event\EventInterface $event)
    {
        parent::beforeFilter($event);
        // Configure the login action to not require authentication, preventing
        // the infinite redirect loop issue
        $this->Authentication->addUnauthenticatedActions(['login', 'add']);
    }

    public function login()
    {
        $this->request->allowMethod(['get', 'post']);
        $result = $this->Authentication->getResult();
        // regardless of POST or GET, redirect if user is logged in
        if ($result && $result->isValid()) {
            // redirect to /articles after login success
            $redirect = $this->request->getQuery('redirect', [
                'controller' => 'Articles',
                'action' => 'index',
            ]);

            return $this->redirect($redirect);
        }
        // display error if user submitted and authentication failed
        if ($this->request->is('post') && !$result->isValid()) {
            $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password'));
        }
        $this->Authorization->skipAuthorization();
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        $result = $this->Authentication->getResult();
        // regardless of POST or GET, redirect if user is logged in
        if ($result && $result->isValid()) {
            $this->Authentication->logout();

            return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']);
        }
        $this->Authorization->skipAuthorization();
    }
}

This is the appcontroller file I also put the code from documentation
AppController
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

/**
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (https://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (https://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * For full copyright and license information, please see the LICENSE.txt
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (https://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link      https://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @since     0.2.9
 * @license   https://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php MIT License
 */
namespace App\Controller;

use Cake\Controller\Controller;

/**
 * Application Controller
 *
 * Add your application-wide methods in the class below, your controllers
 * will inherit them.
 *
 * @link https://book.cakephp.org/5/en/controllers.html#the-app-controller
 */
class AppController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Initialization hook method.
     *
     * Use this method to add common initialization code like loading components.
     *
     * e.g. `$this->loadComponent('FormProtection');`
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(): void
    {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->loadComponent('Flash');

        /*
         * Enable the following component for recommended CakePHP form protection settings.
         * see https://book.cakephp.org/5/en/controllers/components/form-protection.html
         */
        //$this->loadComponent('FormProtection');

        $this->loadComponent('Authentication.Authentication');

        // for all controllers in our application, make index and view
        // actions public, skipping the authentication check
        $this->Authentication->addUnauthenticatedActions(['index', 'view']);
        $this->loadComponent('Authorization.Authorization');
    }
}

This is the policyfile which was created by policy command mentioned in the authorization documentation . There are errors in the isAuthor and getIdentifier methods i don't know why
ArticlesPolicy.php
   <?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Policy;

use App\Model\Entity\Article;
use Authorization\IdentityInterface;

/**
 * Article policy
 */
class ArticlePolicy
{
    /**
     * Check if $user can add Article
     *
     * @param \Authorization\IdentityInterface $user The user.
     * @param \App\Model\Entity\Article $article
     * @return bool
     */
    public function canAdd(IdentityInterface $user, Article $article)
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Check if $user can edit Article
     *
     * @param \Authorization\IdentityInterface $user The user.
     * @param \App\Model\Entity\Article $article
     * @return bool
     */
    public function canEdit(IdentityInterface $user, Article $article)
    {
        return $this->isAuthor($user, $article);
    }

    /**
     * Check if $user can delete Article
     *
     * @param \Authorization\IdentityInterface $user The user.
     * @param \App\Model\Entity\Article $article
     * @return bool
     */
    public function canDelete(IdentityInterface $user, Article $article)
    {
        return $this->isAuthor($user, $article);
    }

    /**
     * Check if $user can view Article
     *
     * @param \Authorization\IdentityInterface $user The user.
     * @param \App\Model\Entity\Article $article
     * @return bool
     */
    public function canView(IdentityInterface $user, Article $article)
    {
        return $article->user_id === $user->getIdentifier();
    }
}


I believe your skipAuthorization call in UsersController::login must come at the top of that function, not the end. As it stands, if a redirect situation occurs, that line is never reached.

You have to define skipAuthorization before find anything, in case you want to Authorize you have to do it before make any access or mofication.
An example :
 public function login()
    {
        $this->Authorization->skipAuthorization(); //  <---- HERE
        $this->request->allowMethod(['get', 'post']);
        $result = $this->Authentication->getResult();
        // regardless of POST or GET, redirect if user is logged in
        if ($result && $result->isValid()) {
            // redirect to /articles after login success
            $redirect = $this->request->getQuery('redirect', [
                'controller' => 'Articles',
                'action' => 'index',
            ]);

            return $this->redirect($redirect);
        }
        // display error if user submitted and authentication failed
        if ($this->request->is('post') && !$result->isValid()) {
            $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password'));
        }
    }

As you can see on your add() function on the ArticlesController.php :
    $article = $this->Articles->newEmptyEntity();
    $this->Authorization->authorize($article);
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $article = $this->Articles->patchEntity($article, $this->request->getData());
            if ($this->Articles->save($article)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The article has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('The article could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
        $users = $this->Articles->Users->find('list', limit: 200)->all();
        $this->set(compact('article', 'users', 'tags'));


        // Get a list of tags.
        $tags = $this->Articles->Tags->find('list')->all();

        // Set tags to the view context
        $this->set('tags', $tags);

        $this->set('article', $article);
        */

Hope it helps!
